# .Net Core 3.1.5 not able to connect to API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I’ve written my first real world .Net Core API for my company. My application is a Web API and it in turn will call a 3rd party API to get some data, then make some data changes, and then return the data through my API.

I’ve worked through all my issues on my local development machine and got it to work as expected. I then moved the application to our STAGE environment for testing and it will not connected to the 3rd parties API. I'm not seeing any errors in my Try...Catch, it's just returned NULL data.

Here is the kicker, if I call the 3rd party API using Postman on the STAGE server I get data as expected. I've even logged the URL I'm using to call the 3rd party in my log files, pulled that out of the logs and put into Postman to make sure I didn't misspell something. Still Postman works but my API doesn't.
Due to the delay in working through my .Net Core issues I ended up having to pull the plug on my Core API. I then wrote the same API using .Net 4.6.2 and it works completely as expected in both our STAGE and PROD environments.

Now I’m back to trying to figure out how I can get .Net Core to work in scenarios like this so that we can move away from .Net and use Core going forward.

The only thing I can think of is the fact that our company makes us go through a Proxy server. In the .Net 4.6.2 application I can easily add the proxy setting in my web.config file. However, I’ve done a bunch of research and some trial/error trying to set the proxy server in my Core API without any luck. I’ve opened up one of my MSDN cases with Microsoft and haven’t made any progress there either. They have the case opened under IIS instead of .Net and the only thing that he has come up with is that I have to get with the 3rd party company and do some network tracing. Well, that’s pretty much not going to happen especially when the .Net 4.6 works. The 3rd party company is not very large, has a very small dev team and they are swamped with fixes and updates we need from their API.

Has anyone been able to successfully add their Proxy server information to a .Net Core application?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried `DefaultProxy` property on `HttpClient`?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=netcore-3.1

I found this article in my google search, let me know if it works.

https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/dotnet-core-http-client-proxy-and-localhost

Comment: I have not seen the DefaultProxy doc you sent. I'll look into that and let you know. Trying to fit this in between other work but I'll try to get to it today or tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Best way is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in first request between working and non working.  Then make headers in c# look like the working headers.  Net 4.6 and core 3.1 should work the same.  I suspect you MAY have a TLS authentication error like 1000's of others the last month.  5 years ago it was decided to discontinue TLS 1.0/1.1 and go to TLS 1.2. Microsoft pushed a Security patch in June on server to disable TLS 1.0/1.1.  If your client is still requesting TLS 1.0/1.1 you have an issue.  Make sure any API have been updated for TLS 1.2.

Comment: Converted to HttpClient and was able to add a Proxy. I posted the answer in case it helps someone else out. Thanks for the comments which pointed lead me to try some another option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some comments here it lead me to look into using the .Net HttpClient. I was using RestSharp to call the API since that is what we were using in our .Net framework. I could never find out how to add a Proxy server to RestSharp.

Based on the comments, I converted my API to use HttpClient and then added the Proxy server to it. I was able to get data to return from the 3rd party API. I then moved it over to my STAGE environment and it worked!!!

Here is what I used for converting to HttpClient and Proxy as well as the code I came up with. I hope this helps someone else down the road.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-5_xI3W0dk

https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/dotnet-core-http-client-proxy-and-localhost

```
var raUserName = _config.GetSection("RAUsername").Value;
var raPassword = _config.GetSection("RAPassword").Value;

var webProxy = new WebProxy(new Uri(_config["ProxyUri"]), BypassOnLocal: false);

var proxyHttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = webProxy,
    UseProxy = true,
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(proxyHttpClientHandler);

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    AuthenticationSchemes.Basic.ToString(),
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{raUserName}:{raPassword}"))
    );


var raData = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(raData))
{
    listRaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RaShift>>(raData);
}

return listRaData;
```

applicationsettings.json

```
"RAUrl": "https://raservice.com/",
"ProxyUri": "http://proxyservername.com:9090",
```